# "display:flex;" is not working. (CSS, JavaScript, React ,React Router V6)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have been having a problem with "display: flex;" to locate the "create a post" part to next to the side menu bar(Home, Profile etc.) , but it seems "display: flex;" does not work and it is located vertically instead. I have been thinking it is because I am using div in a wrong way or because of react router V6. Can anyone help with locating it horizontally? Thank you.

My codes and the result image is as below.

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import LoginHeader from "./LoginHeader.js";
import { Outlet } from "react-router";
import Login from "./Login.js";
import RegisterHeader from "./RegisterHeader.js";
import Register from "./Register.js";
import HomeHeader from "./HomeHeader.js";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar.js";
import Post from "./Post.js";
import News from "./News.js";

function App() {
  return (
      <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Routes>
          <Route path = "/" element = {<LoginHeader />} />
        </Routes>
        <Routes>
             <Route path = "/" element = {<Login />} />
        </Routes>
        <Routes>
          <Route path = "/register" element = {<RegisterHeader />} />
        </Routes>
        <Routes>
          <Route path = "/register" element = {<Register />} />
        </Routes>
        <Routes>
          <Route path = "/home" element = {<HomeHeader />} />
        </Routes>
          <Routes>
            <Route path = "/home" element = {<div className = "appBody"> <Sidebar /> </div>} />
          </Routes>
          <Routes>
            <Route path = "/home" 
            element = {<div className = "homePosts"> <Post /> </div>} />
          </Routes>
          <Routes>
            <Route path = "/home" element = {<News />} />
          </Routes>
          </div>
      </Router>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

**App.css**

```
.appBody {
    display: flex;
}

.homePosts {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXF0k.png)

Answer (score 0):

Import App.css file in App.js or root file index.js.

Like this , if css file is in same folder

```
import './App.css';
```

Comment: Oh god, I was missing the most crucial part. I really appreciate your answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening reason of the wrong placed div and flex property, update your code like this, it will work.

```
   <div className="App">
     <Routes>
       <Route path="/" element={<h1>Login Header</h1>} />
     </Routes>
     <Routes>
       <Route path="/" element={<h2>Login</h2>} />
     </Routes>
     <Routes>
       <Route path="/register" element={<h3>Register Header</h3>} />
     </Routes>
     <Routes>
       <Route path="/register" element={<h4>Register</h4>} />
     </Routes>
     <Routes>
       <Route path="/home" element={<h5>HomeHeader</h5>} />
     </Routes>
     <div className="container">
       <Routes>
         <Route path="/home" element={<h6>Sidebar</h6>} />
       </Routes>
       <div className="appBody">
         <Routes>
           <Route
             path="/home"
             element={
               <div className="homePosts">
                 <p>Post</p>
               </div>
             }
           />
         </Routes>
         <Routes>
           <Route path="/home" element={<i>News</i>} />
         </Routes>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </Router>



.container {
display: flex;
}
.appBody {
display: flex;
flex: 1;
}
.homePosts {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
flex: 1;
}
```